# how can i add some random number before my min.js file , using grunt or gulp

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp

How can i add some random number before my javascript file,using grunt or gulp.
something like this ,

```html
<script src="js/86c1b2a5.appBundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: go with  (new Date()).getTime() instead of a random number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're possibly looking for a package like [`gulp-rev`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev).

Hope that helps you out!